# How to fetch the complete statement using UNIX Commands

Tags: unix, sed, cut, oracle-apps

We are using Oracle Apps where we also develop programs using UNIX. In our Oracle Apps UNIX program, while running a program, we will pass parameters and the parameter values will be stored in $1 value. And this $1 will also contain other information like instance, what is program id, program ran user name and user id etc., as below

```
XX_VENDOR_ACH_HOST FCP_REQID=9946271 FCP_LOGIN="APPS/trn12fnd" FCP_USERID=127 FCP_USERNAME="USERNAME" FCP_PRINTER="noprint" FCP_SAVE_OUT=Y FCP_NUM_COPIES=0 "TEST Pay Batch 021120-c"
```

here, **TEST Pay Batch 021120-c** is the only parameter value. Now, I need to fetch this parameter value. So, I wrote the command as below

`echo $1 | cut -d" " -f9 | sed 's/"//g'`

But, it is just printing the word **TEST** not the complete value. Can anyone please help me with the complete command to fetch **TEST Pay Batch 021120-c**

Regards,
Srivathsava

Comment: You are squishing all this into $1 ?? Why?

Comment: Perhaps all fields starting with 9 using `cut -9-`, but this will walt when the `USERNAME` has a space. Can you change how the data is concatenated or give more details how to `cut`(maybe afer first space after `FCP_NUM_COPIES`).

Comment: Is it place always on the end of line?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming;

- The parameter value is enclosed with double-quotes
- The parameter value is located at the end of `$1`

then how about;

```
echo "$1" | sed 's/.*"\([^"]\+\)"$/\1/'
```

which outputs:

```
TEST Pay Batch 021120-c
```

If my assumptions are incorrect and if the parameter value string has
some distinct characteristics (e.g. it starts with `TEST Pay Batch`),
please let me know. Then I'll tweak the regex to extract the parameter value.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the parameter value is located at the end of `$1` something like can do the work:

```
echo $1|awk -F\" '{print $(NF-1)}'
```

Comment: I tried both. But none worked.

When I tried (Using Putty version 0.63)
echo $1|awk -F\" '{print $(NF-1)}' as

*echo XX_VENDOR_ACH_HOST FCP_REQID=9946271 FCP_LOGIN="APPS/trn12fnd" FCP_USERID=127 FCP_USERNAME="USERNAME" FCP_PRINTER="noprint" FCP_SAVE_OUT=Y FCP_NUM_COPIES=0 "TEST Pay Batch 021120-c"|awk -F\" '{print $(NF-1)}'*

It printed as

*XX_VENDOR_ACH_HOST FCP_REQID=9946271 FCP_LOGIN=APPS/trn12fnd FCP_USERID=127 FCP_USERNAME=USERNAME FCP_PRINTER=noprint FCP_SAVE_OUT=Y FCP_NUM_COPIES=0 TEST Pay Batch 021120-c*

Thanks and Regards,
Srivathsava

Comment: echo "$1" | sed 's/.*"\([^"]\+\)"$/\1/' as

*echo "XX_VENDOR_ACH_HOST FCP_REQID=9946271 FCP_LOGIN="APPS/trn12fnd" FCP_USERID=127 FCP_USERNAME="USERNAME" FCP_PRINTER="noprint" FCP_SAVE_OUT=Y FCP_NUM_COPIES=0 "TEST Pay Batch 021120-c"" | sed 's/.*"\([^"]\+\)"$/\1/'*

The output is as

*XX_VENDOR_ACH_HOST FCP_REQID=9946271 FCP_LOGIN=APPS/trn12fnd FCP_USERID=127 FCP_USERNAME=USERNAME FCP_PRINTER=noprint FCP_SAVE_OUT=Y FCP_NUM_COPIES=0 TEST Pay Batch 021120-c*

Comment: 1. The values: FCP_REQID, FCP_LOGIN, FCP_USERID, FCP_USERNAME, FCP_PRINTER, FCP_SAVE_OUT,FCP_NUM_COPIES will be common (even though the values vary)
2. Out Program parameters will vary. As of now only one parameter (Payment Batch. Whose value as of now is: **TEST Pay Batch 021120-c**).
If new parameters are added, I am pretty sure those will be added after this Payment Batch parameter only.
As of now, please help me to fetch that Payment batch value by considering it as not at ending

Comment: One more note is:

Comment: 3. The value may not always be as **TEST Pay Batch 021120-c** (with spaces). It can be as without spaces (**TEST_Pay_Batch_021120-c**). But ofcourse, we are not using any special characters. Only alphanumeric, underscore and hyper we are using